# OpenGL only first texture render in fb0

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to attach two textures of Gaussian blur to a fbo in order to subtract them in the shader (return c2-c in dog) but the first texture gives strange results. I tried to find the problem but I do not see where it is. If anyone can enlighten me I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Here is the C code:

```
  static void draw(void) {
  static int b1 = 0;
  static int b2 = 50;

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);

  blur(_vao, b1, _tId, _fboTex[0], 1, 0);  
  glUseProgram(0);  

  blur(_vao, b2, _tId, _fboTex[0], 1, 1);
  glUseProgram(0);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _dim[0], _dim[1], 0, 0, _dim[0], _dim[1], GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
  //glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _dim[0], _dim[1], _dim[0]/2, 0, _dim[0], _dim[1], GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

void tex_to_shader(GLuint tid, char * sampler_name, GLuint num_tex){
  glActiveTexture(!num_tex ? GL_TEXTURE0 : GL_TEXTURE1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);  
  glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(blurPId, sampler_name), num_tex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);
}

void blur(GLuint plate_vao, GLuint radius, GLuint in, GLuint out, GLuint nb_iterations, GLuint current_texture) {
  int i, n;
  GLuint temp, rin = in;
  glGenTextures(1, &temp);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, temp);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  radius = radius > MAX_RADIUS ? MAX_RADIUS : radius;

  for(n = 0; n < (int)nb_iterations; n++) {
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, !current_texture ? GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 : GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, i == 0 ? temp : out,  0);
      glUseProgram(blurPId);
      glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(blurPId,  "inv"), i ? 1 : 0);
      glUniform1fv(glGetUniformLocation(blurPId, "weight"), MAX_RADIUS, &weights[(radius * (radius - 1)) >> 1]);
      glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(blurPId, "offset"), MAX_RADIUS, (i % 2) ? offsetH : offsetV);
      glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(blurPId,  "nweights"), radius);
      glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glBindVertexArray(plate_vao);
      tex_to_shader(rin, !current_texture ? "blur0" : "blur1", current_texture);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); 
      glBindVertexArray(0);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    rin = out;
  }
    glDeleteTextures(1, &temp);
}
```

Here is our fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D blur0;
uniform sampler2D blur1;

uniform int current_texture;
uniform int nweights;
uniform float weight[128];
uniform vec2 offset[128];

in  vec2 vsoTexCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;

vec4 dog(sampler2D a, sampler2D b){

    vec4 c  = texture(a, vsoTexCoord.st) * weight[0];
    vec4 c2 = texture(b, vsoTexCoord.st) * weight[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < nweights; i++) {
        c  += texture(a, vsoTexCoord.st + offset[i]) * weight[i];
        c  += texture(a, vsoTexCoord.st - offset[i]) * weight[i];
        c2 += texture(b, vsoTexCoord.st + offset[i]) * weight[i];
        c2 += texture(b, vsoTexCoord.st - offset[i]) * weight[i];
    }
    return c;
}

vec4 gray(vec4 c){
  float moyenne = 0.2126 * c.r + 0.7152 * c.g + 0.0722 * c.b;
  return vec4(moyenne, moyenne, moyenne, 1.0);
}

void main(void) {

  fragColor = dog(blur0,blur1);
  //fragColor = gray(fragColor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a framebuffer with multiple color attachments, then you have to specify the color attachment(s), which should be written to. The color buffer(s) in which should be drawn, can be specified by [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml).

e.g. If only should be drawn on `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` the this can be specified like this:

```
GLenum attachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;
glDrawBuffers(1, &attachment);
```

In your case this mans you have to choose the proper color attachment at the begin of the function `blur`:

```
void blur(GLuint plate_vao, GLuint radius, GLuint in, GLuint out,
    GLuint nb_iterations, GLuint current_texture) {

    GLenum attachment = !current_texture ? GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 : GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;
    glDrawBuffers(1, &attachment);  

    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested your solution but the first texture attached (variable c in dog) remains random. Is there something else missing?